# Returning a file in asp net core 3.0 is leaking memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have this method.

```
[HttpGet("view/{fileId}/{width}/{height}/{name}")]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> View(Guid fileId, int width, int height, string name)
{
    var fileInfo = await _fileViewer.GetImageInfo(fileId, width, height);
    FileStream f = new FileStream(fileInfo.FilePath, FileMode.Open);
    return File(f, fileInfo.MimeType);
}
```

Which simply returns a rezised image to the browser. It works. But as far as I can tell it leaks memory.

`FileStream f` is never disposed.

I can see my servers Memory being every so slowly used up.

If I add a `using` statement in there I get an error that the stream is closed, ie the using statement closes before the file is returned to the user.

How should this be done properly?

**UPDATE 1**.
This:

```
using (FileStream f = new FileStream(fileInfo.FilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    return File(f, fileInfo.MimeType);
}
```

yields

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'Cannot access a closed file.'.

Comment: Can you include the code you had implemented for your `using` statement? Obviously, the correct answer is to either explicitly call `Dispose()` or to wrap your `FileStream` in a `using` statement, but we'll need to evaluate why your `using` statement wasn't working.

Comment: you could try copying your stream to a byte array and use another overload of File method. you can close stream before request ends in this case.

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo I tried that, and it works too, but I would prefer to stream the file to the user. I might be wrong, but I think that way it does not get loaded into RAM.

Comment: If your hypothesis was true then everyone who uses this construct in their application would be having memory leaks. Since they aren't, I think you'll find that it's not this method that's leaking memory.

Comment: @IanKemp you may be correct, I am hoping I am wrong, and its just a lazy GC. But it's eating an awful lot of ram. The rest of the code just does a database request and returns a path. There are no other streams or such. And im using that same method for other things which are not continuously eating more ram.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/FileStreamResultExecutor.cs#L31) is where the `Stream` you pass in to that `File` method is cleaned up.

Comment: @Jens I have exactly the same issue. FIleStream is eating an awful lot of ram and is causing other process in the machine to fail. How did you overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Asp.net Core file-providers instead of manually reading the files using system.IO.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1

but if you don't want to use dependency injection and inject fileProvider to your controller, this trick should work for you :

```cs
var fileInfo = await _fileViewer.GetImageInfo(fileId, width, height);
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileInfo.FilePath);
IFileProvider x = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileInfo.FilePath));
IFileInfo fi =  x.GetFileInfo(fileName);
 // you can use your mime type as second argumant. (fileInfo.MimeType)
return File(fi.CreateReadStream(), MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet , fileName);
```